# Error removing UniSharp laravel-ckeditor with composer

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, composer-php, laravel-5.5

I installed laravel-ckeditor via composer in my Laravel 5.5 project as described on their GitHub (https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor). Now i don't need it anymore and want to remove it. I executed `composer remove unisharp/laravel-ckeditor` but i get this error messge:

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>
> Class 'Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider' not found

I have on idea what causes this error. I tried reinstalling and removing it several times, but i always get the same error message.
Thanks for any help.
Edit: The error is caused by artisan. I can't execute php artisan cache:clear anymore and directly before the error, composer prints
`> @php artisan package:discover`
into the console.

Comment: Have you removed its entry in `ServiceProvider.php` and deleted its **published** *vendor resources*?

Comment: Yes i did both.